# Loading CSV file to create objects of a class (Python, Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, database, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am try to build a database of all MLB and minor league baseball players. Keeping track of what teams they are on, transactions, and eventually statistics.

It is a huge database, and I'm not far along yet, but if the file shuts down in Jupyter Notebook I will lose all of the objects I made in my Player class (to create players). I am creating players in the Player class and then using functions to add them to a main dictionary (to make the process of adding easier and quicker). I am creating ID's for the object names, and including a value in the object as the same ID and index number from the dataframe. Then I filter out data to separate teams.

My question is, if I need to save and reload the information back into the Jupyter Notebook, is there any way I can load the same objects from the Player class? A lot of the system I built depends on being able to track the object names of each player and the index number of each player to update information and record information for each player. I included a little bit of my code...

Thanks for any information and help.

```
class Player:
def __init__(self, number, first, last, pos, cls, ht, wt, bat, throw, birthdate, organization, team, level):
    self.number = number
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.pos = pos
    self.cls = cls
    self.ht = ht
    self.wt = wt
    self.bat = bat
    self.throw = throw
    self.birthdate = birthdate
    self.age = (age(self.birthdate))
    self.organization = organization
    self.team = team
    self.level = level

def addDirectory(playerid, ident, x, y, z, i):
    playerid.id = ident

    playerid.status = x
    playerid.active = y
    playerid.expanded = z
    playerid.index = i

    directory['ID'].append(playerid.id)
    directory['First'].append(playerid.first)
    directory['Last'].append(playerid.last)
    directory['Age'].append(playerid.age)
    directory['Organization'].append(playerid.organization)
    directory['Team'].append(playerid.team)
    directory['Level'].append(playerid.level)
    directory['Position'].append(playerid.pos)
    directory['Height'].append(playerid.ht)
    directory['Weight'].append(playerid.wt)
    directory['Bats'].append(playerid.bat)
    directory['Throws'].append(playerid.throw)
    directory['Status'].append(playerid.status)

    if playerid.expanded == True:
        directory['40-Man'].append('Yes')
    else:
        directory['40-Man'].append('No')


    print(playerid.first + ' ' + playerid.last + ' added to Directory')
    print(playerid.id + ' index number is: ' + str(playerid.index))
```

Comment: Do you actually want to create a database?

Comment: Essentially yeah, and then record stats and everything and track team transactions and record game logs to update stats.

Comment: I'd consider using an actual database for this. In case you don't want to, your options are basically to [serialize](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-serialization-for-python/). For example you can use `pickle` to write to disk in binary or use `json` format to encode you object and save them. Note: saving objects that refer to other objects in memory by reference is not really possible (it is a headache nobody wants). But if you can serialize everything. It's rather simple to save the *whole* object.